# überzunehmen or zu übernehmen

Tags: infinitive, separable-verb

Which one is correct and why?

1. Fangt endlich an, Verantwortung zu übernehmen.
2. Fangt endlich an, Verantwortung überzunehmen.

I have learned {zu+infinitive} and I think second one is correct, because of the role of zu in trennbare verb-zu is between two part of verbs - for example in this sentence: {Er versucht, das Fenster aufzumachen.} but in the answer key, first one is correct. Could you please explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Which one is correct?

**Version 1 is correct** because *übernehmen* is **not** a **separable verb** (in German: *trennbares Verb*).

---

## Explanation

*Separable verb* means that the prefix is *trennbar* (separable) from the stem of the verb. There are some prefixes that are never separable (like *ent-*), others are always separable (like *auf-*). *Über-*, however, belongs to the prefixes that are sometimes separable, sometimes not, depending on the particular verb.

In the latter case, you can tell from the stress whether the prefix is separable from the stem: Inseparable verbs are stressed on the syllable following the prefix, while separable verbs are stressed on the first (i.e., the prefix is stressed). Otherwise, you can learn them by heart.

Separable and inseparable verbs can be homonyms, for example the verb *umfahren* with the meaning *to go around sth.* and stress on *-fah-* is indivisible (*zu umfahren*), while the homonymous verb *umfahren* with the meaning *to knock sth. over* and stress on *um-* is divisible (*umzufahren*).

Whether a verb is divisible is also important for the construction of the *Präteritum* and *Perfekt* tense.

---

### Separable verbs

Among the always divisible prefixes are *ab-*, *an-*, *auf-*, *aus-*, *ein-*, *mit-*, *nach-*, *weg-*, *zu-*, and some more.

For example the verb *aufmachen* with the meaning *to open*:

> - Er **machte** das Fenster **auf**.
> - das Fenster **auf***zu***machen**
> - Ich habe das Fenster **auf***ge***macht**.

An example for a separable verb with the not unambiguous prefix *über-* is *übergehen* with the meaning *to pass to so.* and stressed on *über-*:

> - Der Besitz **ging** auf ihn **über**.
> - Der Besitz ist auf ihn **über***ge***gangen**.
> - Fangt endlich an **über***zu***gehen**!

---

### Inseparable verbs

Verbs with the prefixes *be-*, *ent-*, *er-*, *ver-*, *zer-*, and some others always belong to this category.

For instance *verstehen* (*to understand*, stressed on *-ste-*):

> - Ich **verstand** die Regel.
> - Ich habe die Regel **verstanden**.
> - Die Regel *zu* **verstehen**

Also to this category belongs *übernehmen*:

> - Ihr **übernahmt** Verantwortung.
> - Ihr habt Verantwortung **übernommen**.
> - Verantwortung *zu* **übernehmen**

---

## Further reading:

- [learngerman.dw.com](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/trennbare-verben-1/l-40406333/gr-40406521)
- [deutschlernerblog.de](https://deutschlernerblog.de/trennbare-verben-trennbar-oder-untrennbar-listen-erklaerungen-beispiele-uebungen/) with exhaustive lists of prefixes
- [mein-deutschlernbuch.de](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/trennbare-verben.html) with some tables

Comment: I just noticed that *übergehen* works in both ways: "zu übergehen" and "überzugehen", but they mean different things.